# connecting a grill to gas line

Tags: leak, pipe, gas

A technician told me I can simply connect a grill to gas line without any need for tapes. I connected our grill to the gas line without using any tape for isolation. I ran the soapy water test and there was no bubble. The grill was working fine. I am still worried about the leak. Is it necessary to disconnect the grill from the gas line and use tape and redo everything? or is it OK since there was no bubble formation in the soap and water test.

I have put the connection image below.

[image: grill connection to gas line]

Comment: Your question was interrupted mid-thought. You could edit it. While there, it'll be helpful if you mention (or better, show photos) what kind of connectors you're working with. Some are designed to be assembled "dry" with neither tape nor pipe joint compound, but others do require these sealants.

Comment: @GregHill Thanks for the comment. Our grill is https://www.weber.com/US/en/grills/gas-grills/genesis-ll/genesis-ii-s-435-gas-grill-%28natural-gas%29/67006001.html

Comment: Did you add pipe to get the connection made or did you only need to couple it to a quick connect as in the manual?

Comment: @Jack I just needed to couple it to a quick connect as in the manual.

Comment: @GregHill I have added the picture. I would appreciate it if you take a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you ran threaded NPS pipe all the way, you need dope like tape to seal the threads. If it is a traditional flex metal tube , it is a flare connection and tape could cause it to leak. A flare connection is metal to metal seal and there should be nothing between the metal surfaces , except possibly a thin oil film.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not an expert on this subject but just added a photo above in the post. Would you please take a look and see if it is alright not to use tape or dope for this kind of connection? Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with that connection; looks like some quick -connect that would not use tape, but I am speculating.

Answer (score 1):

I will repeat some things in an another answer but if it were me, I would take the quick connect fitting back off and if it has a reducer or adapter added to aid in the connection of the quick connect, remove that too.

I see in the pic the pipe with paint is original install, anything you add beyond that should have a sealant on  the threads before threading on. This could be as simple as pipe dope approved for gas piping. It will be on the label. Reconnect all threaded fittings with a little dab of dope on it and tighten them up like before.

Natural gas is a very low pressure gas and is easily contained within a gas line, much unlike propane which under a LOT of pressure. This is why your pipes are doing well as they are, without the sealant. They will probably do well over the long run, but for me, I would add the pipe dope.